# Проблема при развёртывании WordPress на OpenServer через плагин Duplicator

Tags: php, wordpress

[image: Скрин Duplicator]

Ругается на большой размер пакета (более 2Гб). Что делать в этом случае?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скопировать сайт вручную, а базу поставить через Duplicator

https://snapcreek.com/duplicator/docs/quick-start/#quick-060-q

И на сколько я помню когда копируешь сайт через Duplicator можно исключить файлы, к примеру папку upload с изображениями, что снизит вес файла

Comment: Спасибо за совет!